# Finding out exact match in python

Tags: python-2.7, find

I'm trying to find out a string from list.
Here's the code:

```
    wordlist = ['gedit','leafpad','qstardict','stardict']

    letters = str('stardict')

    for item in wordlist:
        if item.find(letters) != -1:
            print item
```

It's showing 'qstardict' first and then 'stardict'. 
But I want it to show 'stardict' first.
Please help me.

Comment: Um... so exact match first, then substring match? Or some other rule that you're not describing?

Comment: You have a weird manner to do programming. 1/ ``'startdict' == str('startdict')`` is True. Did you understand what ``str()`` is doing ? 2/ In a comment you wrote: _"Here the find() method is acting strangely"_. Not at all. ``item.find('stardict')`` searches for the string ``'stardict'`` in the string ``item``. If **item** is the string ``'qstardict'``, the researched string is found, begining at the index 1. Did you ever read the description of ``str.find()`` ? Did you ever test what returns ``item.find('stardict')`` and to understand what means the **1** returned ?

Comment: 3/ As @JoachimIsaksson underlined it, if you say _"I want it to show 'stardict' first"_ it doesn't mean that you want only the words begining with ``stardict'``, it implies that you want the other "occurences" too, displayed after the researched word ``'stardict'``, and it isn't clear which ones excatly are these other occurences. 4/ If you know the word that you search, and by a comment below it seems you search only it, why do you search it since you know it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ?

```
wordlist = ['stardictionaries','hop','stardicto',
            'stardictionaria', 'jumper',
            'gedit','leafpad','qstardict',
            'stardictionary','stardict',]

def seurch1(deb,wordlist):
    for item in wordlist:
        if item.startswith(deb):
            yield item

def seurch2(deb,wordlist):
    L = len(deb)
    for item in wordlist:
        if item[0:L]==deb:
            yield item

from pprint import pprint

pprint( list(seurch1('stardict',wordlist)) )
print
pprint( sorted(seurch1('stardict',wordlist),key=len) )  

print '--------------------'

pprint( list(seurch2('stardict',wordlist)) )
print
pprint( sorted(seurch2('stardict',wordlist),key=len) )
```

I think that `seurch2()` is faster

result

```
['stardictionaries',
 'stardicto',
 'stardictionaria',
 'stardictionary',
 'stardict']

['stardict',
 'stardicto',
 'stardictionary',
 'stardictionaria',
 'stardictionaries']
--------------------
['stardictionaries',
 'stardicto',
 'stardictionaria',
 'stardictionary',
 'stardict']

['stardict',
 'stardicto',
 'stardictionary',
 'stardictionaria',
 'stardictionaries']
```

### Edit

`seurch1()` and `seurch2()` are two functions that do exactly the same thing.
They are generator functions because of the presence of the keyword `yield` instead of `return` in them.
They act as iterators: they yield an element each time a call is done, as in:

```
for el in seurch2('stardict',wordlist):
    print el
```

But `list(seurch2('stardict',wordlist))` calls all the yielded elements in one shot and returns them in a list.

If you want to sort in alphabetical order, simply do:

```
sorted( seurch2('stardict',wordlist) )
```

because the elements are then sorted on the basis of their string value, and

```
print 'bc' < 'ba'
# False
print 'bc' < 'bda'
# True
print 'bcxyzterry' < 'bda'
# True
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems it will work but very difficult code. Can you give me an easier solution please?

Comment: This is not what I wanted.I want the items to be printed in alphabetical order.Like: stardict,stardicto,stardictionaria,stardictionaries,stardictionary.

Comment: What do you call alphabetical order on your planet ? ``stardict,stardicto,stardictionaria,stardictionaries,stardictionary`` isn't in alphabetical order because the ``o`` after **stardict** in ``stardicto`` is alphabetically after the ``i`` which is after **stardict** in the following words ``stardictionaria,stardictionaries,stardictionary``

Comment: _"very difficult code. Can you give me an easier solution please? "_ Are you kidding ?

Comment: Thanks @eyquem for your sincere help.
Please look: 
In the output stardicto comes before stardictionaria. No problem with 
Alphabetical order until it reaches 'o'.In the second one there
is 'i' after 't'.But 'i' comes before 'o' in alphabet.

Not kidding. Actually, I'm not familier with 'yield', pprint etc.
It's my shortcoming. I'm not blaming you.
Thanks again.

Comment: @user2420437 What-do-you-mean ?? _"In the output"_, you say. WHICH output ?? The one that is above my edit ?? Let us consider the last two ouputed lists in this section above my edit. The first one is the result of ``list(seurch2('stardict',wordlist))``. If I would have written only ``seurch2('stardict',wordlist)``, the ouput would have been ``<generator object seurch2 at 0x011DE800>``. The goal is not to obtain the iterator, it is to obtain all the values yielded by the iterator. The way to obtain this, is to make the iterator entirely read by ``list()``

Comment: @user2420437 The second list `['stardict', 'stardicto', 'stardictionary', 'stardictionaria', 'stardictionaries']`` is the result of ``sorted(seurch2('stardict',wordlist),key=len)`` . I never said that this is a list sorted on the basis of the alphabetical order. It is a list sorted on the basis of the legth of the elements, that's determined by the ``key=len`` part. If you wondered about this ``key``'signification, you should have learned it in the docs.

Comment: @user2420437 Finally, I draw your attention to this sentence I wrote too: _"If you want to sort in alphabetical order, simply do:
sorted( seurch2('stardict',wordlist) )"_ . I didn't wrote the ouput of this instruction. Couldn't you do it yourself ? Didn't you see this sentence ? Didn't you understand this instruction ? Did you read the doc about ``sorted`` ? Mystery for me.

Comment: @user2420437 Your way of doing is weird for me. - My advice is that you begin to read carefully the doc instead of waiting after the others to take you by hand to explain all in details. - And to improve the way you communicate because it is weird and laborious

Comment: @user2420437 Despite my critics, will you think that my answer deserves to be accepted ? Acceptance is done by clicking on the stripe that is situated under the three elements at the left of my answer (an upvote button-a number-a downvote button). I believe you can only accept answers, not doing upvotes or downvotes because you haven't enough reputation points.

Comment: Well. You're a fair person. I've just seen the upvote and acceptance. I hope what I said will help you to become better in communicating on a forum and to make programming.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: A last attempt to do what you're asking, if this is not what you want, please update the question with a complete description of what you need help with;

This gets *all words that start with your substring, in alphabetical order*;

```
result = sorted(x for x in wordlist if x.startswith(letters))
```

Comment: Actually, size of letter is not important for me.
What I want to do is, whenever I type 'a', items 
with 'a' as first letter will appear.
If I type 'ca', items with letter 'c' first and 'a'
second will appear.There will be thousands of 
items in the list.

Comment: n@user2420437 Could you please update the question with the correct rules then? Your question says you want `stardict` _first_, which implies that you want `qstartdict` too. Following what you added now, only `stardict` should show up at all since `qstardict` does not start with the same letters...?

Comment: No problem if both strings are printed. 
I will append the output words into a list.
Since my target string is 'stardict',
that should be in the first index of the list.
Unfortunately, 'qstardict' takes the first
place.Here the find() method is acting strangely.
It catches 'qstardict' first since it comes earlier than
'stardict' in the wordlist.

Comment: @user2420437 Did you try the solution in the answer above? In what way does it do the wrong thing?